# Вставить значения в таблицу по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть первый датафрейм df_org:

| ИНН | Доход-2018 | Расход-2018 | Прибыль-2018 | Доход-2019 | Расход-2019 | Прибыль-2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 525715668088 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 525715197343 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 525714499422 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Второй датафрейм df_fin:

| ИНН | Доход | Расход | Прибыль | Дата-сост |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 525715668088 | 200000 | 50000 | 150000 | 31.12.2018 |
| 525715668088 | 100000 | 50000 | 50000 | 31.12.2019 |
| 525714499422 | 300000 | 50000 | 250000 | 31.12.2018 |

Должны получить на выходе:
df_org_fin:

| ИНН | Доход-2018 | Расход-2018 | Прибыль-2018 | Доход-2019 | Расход-2019 | Прибыль-2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 525715668088 | 200000 | 50000 | 150000 | 100000 | 50000 | 50000 |
| 525715197343 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 525714499422 | 300000 | 50000 | 250000 |  |  |  |

Вот мой код. Он вроде бы работает, но чувствую он сильно не оптимизирован и с циклами я миллион записей буду до второго пришествия формировать итоговую таблицу. Подскажите, как сделать правильно?

```
        
a=1
b=1
i=1
for inn in df_org['ИНН']:
    print('ИНН', inn, "Строка", i)
    i+=1
    index_2018 = df_fin.loc[(df_fin['ИНН']==inn)&df_fin['Дата_сост']=='31.12.2018')].index
    index_2019 = df_fin.loc[(df_fin['ИНН']==inn)&df_fin['Дата_сост']=='31.12.2019')].index
    
    if index_2018.empty is not True:      
        df_org.loc[(df_org['ИНН']==inn), "Доход_2018"] = (df_fin.at[index_2018.to_list()[0], 'Доход'])
        df_org.loc[(df_org['ИНН']==inn), "Расход_2018"] = (df_fin.at[index_2018.to_list()[0], 'Расход']) 
        df_org.loc[(df_org['ИНН']==inn), "Прибыль_2018"] = (df_fin.at[index_2018.to_list()[0], 'Прибыль'])
        print('Добавлен 2018, запись:', a)
        a+=1

    if index_2019.empty is not True:      
        df_org.loc[(df_org['ИНН']==inn), "Доход_2019"] = (df_fin.at[index_2018.to_list()[0], 'Доход'])
        df_org.loc[(df_org['ИНН']==inn), "Расход_2019"] = (df_fin.at[index_2018.to_list()[0], 'Расход']) 
        df_org.loc[(df_org['ИНН']==inn), "Прибыль_2019"] = (df_fin.at[index_2018.to_list()[0], 'Прибыль']) 
        print('Добавлен 2019, запись:', b)
        b+=1
    
print('Всего записей 2018:', a) 
print('Всего записей 2019:', b) 
print('Итого обработано:', i)
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за таблицы такого вида. Не получается что-то по рекомендации формата GitHub-flavored markdown сделать((

Answer (score 1):

Из второго фрейма делаем сводную таблицу, где кроме данных формируется мультииндекс по столбцам, где статья - первый уровень, а год - второй. "ИНН" становится индексом (по строкам). Формируем из колоночного мультииндекса одноуровневый индекс для колонок вида "Статья-Год". Затем сортируем столбцы и вытаскиваем "ИНН" из индекса в столбец. В конце делаем внешнее соединение второго фрейма с колонкой "ИНН" первого фрейма, чтобы не выпали "пустые" ИНН, т.е. по которым нет данных во втором фрейме.
Основная работа происходит в методе `.pivot_table()`, все остальное - оформительские штуки.
При необходимости NaNы в итоговом фрейме можно заменить на 0 или '' с помощью `.fillna()`.
Примечание. От первого фрейма я оставил только столбец 'ИНН', остальное не нужно.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ИНН': [525715668088, 525715197343, 525714499422]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ИНН': [525715668088, 525715668088, 525714499422], 'Доход': [200000, 100000, 300000],
                    'Расход': [50000, 50000, 50000], 'Прибыль': [150000, 50000, 250000],
                    'Дата-сост': ['31.12.2018', '31.12.2019', '31.12.2018']})

df3 = (df2.pivot_table(columns='Дата-сост', values=['Доход', 'Расход', 'Прибыль'], index='ИНН', aggfunc=sum, dropna=False))
df3.columns = [f'{i[0]}-{i[1][-4:]}' for i in df3.columns]
articles_order = {c: str(i) for i, c in enumerate('ДРП')} # словарь для последующей сортировки столбцов в порядке 'Доход' - 'Расход' - 'Прибыль'
df3 = (df3[sorted(df3.columns, key=lambda x: x[-4:] + articles_order[x[0]])].reset_index().merge(df1['ИНН'], how='outer'))
print(df3)
```

```
            ИНН  Доход-2018  Расход-2018  Прибыль-2018  Доход-2019  Расход-2019  Прибыль-2019
0  525714499422    300000.0      50000.0      250000.0         NaN          NaN           NaN
1  525715668088    200000.0      50000.0      150000.0    100000.0      50000.0       50000.0
2  525715197343         NaN          NaN           NaN         NaN          NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Алексей! И за корректировку моих таблиц и за развернутый ответ! Все работает!!!